# При уменьшении размера страницы, нарушается структура моих блоков

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

```js
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav()
            $('.modal').modal();
        });     
        $('.parallax').parallax();
        $('.carousel').carousel();
        $("#bannerNav").addClass("cvitae-demo-nav");
        

       
      
    </script>
```

```css
.carousel{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    perspective:500px;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    transform-origin:0% 50%;
}
.carousel-item{
    height:280px;
    width:400px;
}
.service-carousel.carousel-item{
    width:400px;
    top:-74px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="carousel carousel-slider" data-indicators="true">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <div>
                            <div class="fixed container">
                                <div class="row" style="margin-left:-0.75rem;margin-right:-0.75rem;">
                                    <div class="col s12 m10 offset-m1 l8 offset-l2">
                                        <div class="carousel-item">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="card hoverable small">
                                                    <div class="card-image">
                                                        <img src="~/Content/curves-2210622_960_720.png" height="200" width="350" alt="" />
                                                        <span class="card-title"> @Html.Raw(item.nbaslik)</span>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="card-content">
                                                        <p>@Html.Raw(item.nicerik)</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="card-action">
                                                        <a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("HomeViewPage", "Home")'" href="">Devamını oku</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

[image: на весь экран][image: когда уменьшается размер страницы]

Comment: вы е хотите что бы вам помогли или дали ответ который вас удовлетворит ? весь код как и jQuery приведённый вами не работает как и вёрстка ваша вместе с css от bootstrap ... отредактируйте ваш сниппет таким образом что бы ваш код воспроизводился ...а так не ясна суть вопроса так и теги в вопросу

Comment: Мне нужна помощь почему когда я уменьшил размер страницы коробка не уменьшается вместе страницы.я использую Materialize Css  не bootstrap.Простите меня за мой русский

Comment: коробка ? у вас размер фиксированный 400рх .. о какой коробке речь ? о слайдере ?

Comment: Коробка это, видимо, контейнер. Ящик - (box) - блок

Comment: @tutankhamun  ... аж не ловко становится ... мне не ясно о чём вопрос..не минусую из за плохого русского

Comment: да о слайдере.kogda ya umenshayu stranichu slayder ne umenshaetsa a ishchizaet

Comment: kak v izobrazheniye